# Tratar retorno de Post em Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, json

Opa,

Tenho uma página em que é executado um SetInterval de segundos em javascript, esta página captura os dados das divs e envia via post, sendo que estes dados enviados não são fixos, as vezes, pode ser enviado 1 ou mais de um.

No envio, trato essa quantidade de inteiros enviados e separo-o por virgulas, ou seja, o arquivo .php recebe no formato `registro_id = 1, 3, 4, 5`.

Lá no php dou um explode no valor e um foreach para a consulta de dados e retorno em Json. O problema é que se for enviado mais de um valor via javascript, serão retornados via json a quantidade de resposta obtida na consulta.

O formato de resposta em json é:

```
Se enviado apenas um ID:
[{"registro":{"registro_id":"1","estado":"1","preco":"R$ 5,99","usuario_id":"18","usuario_nome" :"joao"}}]

Se enviado apenas mais de um ID:
[{"registro":{"registro_id":"1","estado":"1","preco":"R$ 5,99","usuario_id":"18","usuario_nome" :"joao"}}]
[{"registro":{"registro_id":"3","estado":"1","preco":"R$ 3,99","usuario_id":"48","usuario_nome" :"maria"}}]
```

O problema é que preciso receber esses valores em minha função javascript e atualizar os campos da página, mas, são recebidos valores distintos para campos com classes distintas, tentei assim:

```
    usuario_id   = $('.user-id-'+ registro_id);
    usuario_nome = $('.user-name-'+ registro_id);
```

Os campos estão com as devidas classes, a variavel `registro_id` é a mesma recebida na função no setinterval, mas, isso só funciona se é enviado apenas um item ao .php, se são enviados dois, nada acontece.

Exemplo resumido:

DIVS

```
<div class="content_item" id="registro_1" title="registro_1">
        <div class="user-name-1" id="coupon-time"></div>
        <div class="user-id-1" id="coupon-price" style="text-align:center"></div>
</div>

<div class="content_item" id="registro_2" title="registro_2">
        <div class="user-name-2" id="coupon-time"></div>
        <div class="user-id-2" id="coupon-price" style="text-align:center"></div>
</div>
```

Função JavaScript

```
function atualizaregistro() {
    var registros = '';

    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });
    $('.content_item').each(function() {
        var new_value = $(this).attr('title');
        if (registros != '') registros = registros + ',';
        registros = registros + new_value;
    });

    if (registros) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '_files/_update_information.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'registro_id=' + registros,
            global: false,
            success: function(data) {


                $.each(data, function(j, item) {

                    var usuario_id = item.registro.usuario_id;
                    var usuario_nome = item.registro.usuario_nome;


                    field_user_id = $('.user-id-' + registro_id);
                    field_user_name = $('.user-name-' + registro_id);

                    field_user_id.text(usuario_id);
                    field_user_name.text(usuario_nome);


                });
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

PHP

```
$registros = explode(',',$_POST['registro_id']);
foreach($registros as $registro_id)
{
    ...Código Consulta BD

    $temp = '{"registro":{"registro_id":"'.$registro_id.'","estado":"1","preco":"'.$preco.'","usuario_id":"'.$usuario_id.'","usuario_nome":"'.$usuario_nome.'"}}';
}

echo "[".$temp."]";
```

Alguem pode ajudar?

Comment: Quando envias dois items ao PHP como é que os distingues no JavaScript e HTML? cada um tem a sua chave como `user-name` ou cada item tem `user-name` e `user-id`?

Comment: No html cada div tem os campos com user-name-ID e user-id-ID, esse ID é o valor enviado ao javascript, e o mesmo consultado no php

Comment: Então o melhor era criares um JSON no javascript com esses IDs... como estás a ir buscar esses valores no JavaScript? podes mostrar um exemplo de HTML com dois items?

Comment: Sim, farei um exemplo, por favor, só um instante

Comment: @Sergio Adicionei o exemplo resumido do código, diretamente na questão

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que o melhor era enviares um JSON, e devolveres um JSON.

O que estás a fazer agora é a criar uma string customizada, a fazê-la "explodir" (explode) no PHP e etc... o melhor é não reinventar a roda.

Sugestão:

```
function atualizaregistro() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });
    var registos = $('.content_item').get().map(function(el) {
        return el.id;
    });

    if (registros) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '_files/_update_information.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {registro_id: JSON.stringify(registos)},
```

depois no PHP:

```
$registros = json_decode($_POST['registro_id']);
$retorno = [];
foreach($registros as $registro_id){
    // etc
    $retorno[] = array(id, estado, preco, etc...)
```

e para devolveres retorna o mesmo, ou pelo menos só uma array:

```
echo json_encode($retorno);
```

Desta maneira sabes no JavaScript que tens a mesma ordem da array e podes fazer:

```
registos.forEach(function(id, i){
    $('#' + id).find('.coupon-time').html(data[i].preco);
    // etc...

});
```

Ou seja:

- cria uma array com os elementos
- passa um JSON para, e do, PHP
- itera essa array de novo e usa o `index` para aceder ao `data`do ajax

**Nota:**: tens IDs duplicados! Só podes ter um ID `coupon-time` por página. Eles têm de ser únicos. No meu exemplo mudei para uma classe, assim agrupas os elementos com a mesma funcionalidade.

Enfim, foi uma sugestão, espero que dê para interpretar e adaptar ao teu código.

Comment: Concordo plenamente, não tenho palavras para agradecer sua sugestão, já estou adaptando-a a meu código, mas, surgiu-me um problema, o php não está reconhecendo a variavel enviada no post

 `Undefined index: registro_id in`

As variaveis no javascript estão corretas e com valor, podeira me dar uma força

Comment: @sNniffer acho que tinha trocado a sintaxe, vê o `data` do ajax de novo e depois no PHP.

Comment: Show de bola, Sergio não querendo abusar muito, mas, me tira uma dúvida rápida.

Estou enviando o json e recebendo do php com sucesso, mas se envio para o php apenas um valor, os dados são retornados com sucesso, se são enviados mais de um valor é retornado os dados referente apenas ao último valor. Lá no php pelo foreach vi que os ID são recebidos corretamente. Ex.: Ao enviar os ID 1 e 3, o foreach é executado e envia os dados apenas referente ao 3.

Abraço